# Dealing with aiohttp session.get() timeout issues for large amout of requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I struggle to find a lot of documentation on **aiohttp**, specially some recent one. I keep going through the same few pages again and again, github issues and documentation mostly and can't find the key to my problem.

**The problem is that while doing a lot of requests, the pending ones timeout before they get to be sent.**

This is due to the request's (*session.get()*) default timeout of 5 minutes which counts from the time the await is done and not the actual request if I understand it well.
Thus I am blocked because leaving **a fixed timeout will cancel (timeout) all the pending requests after that time** or having **timeout set to *None* will make the the program wait indefinitely** on the non responding sites.
The same problem is raised in [this issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3203) but I don't get the workarounds.

Here's my failing code:

```
async def request(session, url):
    try:
        resp = await session.get(url)
    except:
        "FAIL"
    else:
        "SUCCESS"

async def session():
    urls = loadUrls()
    coros = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            coros.append(request(session, url))
        await asyncio.gather(*coros, return_exceptions=True)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete((session()))
    loop.close()
```

I've tried, to set the TCPConnector limit=None, with no success.

I saw some people talking about using asyncio.wait instead of asyncio.gather, but as in the issue 3203 shown above, no success.

I've tried to set a ClientSession per each request with no succes but this might be because my lack of understanding.

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: How do you conclude that your requests "time out before they are sent", once when you turn off the TCPConnector limit? With the limit removed, there should be no "pending"  requests, they should all start out at once. (Some of them might fail due to lacking system resources, but those will fail, not remain in a pending state.) Using asyncio.wait instead of asyncio.gather will make no difference, as gather is just a higher-level API for the same functionality.

Comment: I say that because my results vary a lot from one test to another. Plus I don't know how to get the failed ones to test them separately and I feel that setting the limit to None makes it limiting for scale.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the timeout on your `ClientSession` using [`ClientTimeout`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html?highlight=timeout#aiohttp.ClientTimeout) as follows:

```py
my_timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(
    total=None, # total timeout (time consists connection establishment for a new connection or waiting for a free connection from a pool if pool connection limits are exceeded) default value is 5 minutes, set to `None` or `0` for unlimited timeout
    sock_connect=10, # Maximal number of seconds for connecting to a peer for a new connection, not given from a pool. See also connect.
    sock_read=10 # Maximal number of seconds for reading a portion of data from a peer
)

client_args = dict(
    trust_env=True,
    timeout=my_timeout
)

# Pass args
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(**client_args) as session:
    ...
    # do stuff here
    for url in urls:
        coros.append(request(session, url))
    
    # Try awaiting, if a timeout, do something else
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(*coros, return_exceptions=True)
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print('Timeout!')
```